# Tried to register widget with id but that id is already registered

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have two buttons and would like to load a different custom template widget into a div depending on which button is pressed.  It works fine the first click, but then comes up with the subject error when either of the buttons is clicked again. I've got this very simplified example to try and get the concept working

my template code (there are two very similar to this):

```
define([
  "dojo/_base/declare",
  "dijit/_WidgetBase",
  "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
  "dojo/text!Templates/Person.htm"
], function (declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, personTpl) {
    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
        templateString: personTpl
    });
});
```

my template (there are two very similar to this):

```
<div>
  <p>Bob Jones</p>
</div>
```

Main page:

```
 <body class="claro">

    <script>
        require([
        "dijit/form/Button", 
        "Templates/Person", "Templates/Person2", "dojo/domReady!"
     ], function (Button, Person, Person2) {
         var Button1 = new Button({
             label: "Person1",
             onClick: function () {
                 var p = new Person({}, "page");//error occurs here after a button has been pressed once
             }
         }, "btnPerson1").startup();

         var Button2 = new Button({
             label: "Person2",
             onClick: function () {
                 var p2 = new Person2({}, "page"); //error occurs here after a button has been pressed once
             }
         }, "btnPerson2").startup();
     });
    </script>
    <button id="btnPerson1" type="button"></button>
    <button id="btnPerson2" type="button"></button>
    <div id="page"></div>
  </body>
```

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: My guess is that you need to do something like this. `var p = new Person({}).placeAt("page");`. Hope it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey I took your code and I created a jsfiddle test and now I realized what is your problem.

If I understood correctly you are getting in trouble just when creating the second object and the other ones. For the first widget I believe you are ok.

So, the reason that the first object is ok is because the dojo creates the widget using your id and they have something named widgetid. The widgetid is put in a list and it is just removed from there if you call the destroy method of the widget; however, when you call the destroy method of your widget it will destroy the node. Here is the jsfiddle link that fixes your problem, please let me know if I understood correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/cyeddpe5/26/

```
define("Person",[
  "dojo/_base/declare",
  "dijit/_WidgetBase",
  "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",  
], function (declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, personTpl) {
    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
        templateString: "<div><p>Bob Jones</p></div>"
    });
});
     require([
        "dijit/form/Button", 
        "Person", "dojo/domReady!"
     ], function (Button, Person) {
         var Button1 = new Button({
             label: "Person1",
             onClick: function () {
                 //Here is the trick
                 if(window.p)
                 {
                     window.p.destroy(false);
                     var page = document.createElement("div");
                     dojo.body().appendChild(page);
                     page.setAttribute("id","page");
                 }

                 window.p = new Person({}, "page");//error occurs here after a button has been pressed once
             }
         }, "btnPerson1").startup();
     });
```

I do not like to use id in a div to create my widgets, instead of this I normally use a reference to the widget, but it is up to you. Remember to destroy the widget and recreate the node. I am quite sure that there is a way to destroy the widget keeping the node alive, but I did not have time to find it. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you.  When you speak of using a reference to the widget, how would that work

Comment: Below is the ways to do that:

var node = document.createElement("div"); var myWidget = new Person({}, node); // in this case the myWidet is your reference to the widget, so you can handle it until it is necessary and after that you can call the destroy method of it.

Another way is knowing the id that you have to your widget. With the id you can do that:

myWidget = dijit.byId("your_id");

Please, do not forget to vote in my posts if they are really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Both buttons attempt to create a widget using the same ID (`"page"`), and nothing ever destroys this widget.  Dijit maintains a registry of widgets keyed by their ID, and IDs are naturally expected to be unique, so any attempt to create a widget with an ID of an already-registered widget will fail with that error.

To properly destroy the widget first, either maintain a reference to it (in a variable outside the scope of any of your individual click callbacks) or use [`dijit/registry.byId`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/registry.html#retrieving-a-widget-from-the-registry-using-a-widget-id) to get a reference to the widget again.  Then call its `destroyRecursive` method.  Either way, you should not need to rely on global variables.

Examples: http://jsfiddle.net/zdbvs5c9/

PS: I should also mention that assigning `new Widget(...).startup()` to a variable is meaningless, because `startup` doesn't return anything.  `placeAt` is chainable like that, `startup` isn't (since it isn't always appropriate to immediately call `startup` anyway, since it needs to be called only after the widget is in document flow).

Comment: It is strange that the dijit registry is more global than the context it is created in. I have a single page angular1 application, and even though the html element it was initialized with does not exists anymore when going from one page to another, the dijit reference still exists so it triggers this error when I try to create it again...

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers explain the underlying cause of the error, a simple observation is that it can be triggered by running the dojo parser twice. This can happen if you have both *parseOnLoad* set and also call *parser.parse()*. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    dojoConfig = {
      async: true,
      parseOnLoad: true,
    };

    require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/ready", "dojo/domReady!"],
      function (parser, ready) {
        ready(function () {
          parser.parse();
        });
      }
    );
  </script>
```

The solution is to remove the *parseOnLoad* element - let *parser.parse()* do the work.